# I cant center my icon and text despite no error in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.amber),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Flexible(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.access_time_filled_sharp),
                  Text('Flutter'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),         
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

the center doesn't work in new version of flutter or is it just me? but anyway I searched for it and it was changed to Align which I used but I still cant center my icon and text.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To center the title on `AppBar`, you can use `centerTitle: true` and while using Row widget, it uses  `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max` by default and you need to set `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.amber),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.access_time_filled_sharp),
              Text('Flutter'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

More about [ui/layout in flutter.](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout)